# RhinoMocks is throwing InvalidOperationException in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, rhino-mocks

I have a class which I would like to mock in my test, here is part of it's interface:

```
interface IInventory
{
    Instrument[] GetAllInstrumentsAffectedByFixSide(int fixSideNumber);

    bool IsRegistered<T>(string name, int? fixSideNumber) where T : InventoryObject;
}
```

My record looks like this:

```
using (mockRepository.Record())
{
    inventory.GetAllInstrumentsAffectedByFixSide(0);
    LastCall.Return(new Instrument[0]);

    inventory.Expect(x => x.IsRegistered<TestInstrument>("ActivatorInstrument", null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(true)
}
```

But when I write this in my code-under-test:

```
TestHandler.Inventory.IsRegistered<TestInstrument>("ActivatorInstrument", null)
```

It throws InvalidOperationException. The place where it throws this exception is interesting - it is `MethodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition()`

The sources of it looks like:

```
public override MethodInfo GetGenericMethodDefinition()
{
    if (!IsGenericMethod)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    return RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(m_declaringType, RuntimeMethodHandle.StripMethodInstantiation(this)) as MethodInfo;
}
```

So this method is actually invoked on not generic method. When I placed a breakpoint inside, and checked what this methodInfo is, I found that it is actually not `IsRegistered<>` method, but `GetAllInstrumentsAffectedByFixSide`.

Why Rhino tries to call `GetGenericMethodDefinition` for method `GetAllInstrumentsAffectedByFixSide` inside the mock-call for `IsRegistered<>`? `GetGenericMethodDefinition` call happened previously. It looks like it just confuses these two methods.

The stacktrace:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition()
at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.MethodsEquals(MethodInfo method, ProxyMethodExpectationTriplet triplet)
at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.GetAllExpectationsForProxyAndMethod(Object proxy, MethodInfo method)
at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.CalcExpectedAndActual.Calculate(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.CalcExpectedAndActual..ctor(UnorderedMethodRecorder parent, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.UnexpectedMethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.UnorderedMethodRecorder.DoGetRecordedExpectation(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.MethodRecorders.MethodRecorderBase.GetRecordedExpectation(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.DoMethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.ReplayMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
at IInventoryProxy4a132be1cb07441cafba3f828d3ced66.IsRegistered[T](String name, Nullable`1 fixSideNumber)
at TestHandlerLibrary.DummyFixSideHandler.DoInitialization() in \RTX.Test.TestGear.DummyTestHandlerLibrary\DummyFixSideHandler.cs:line 87
```

**Upd** I did a mistake in the question: I actually setup expectation as:

```
inventory.Expect(x => x.IsRegistered<TestInstrument>("ActivatorInstrument", null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(true);
```

When I change that to direct setup without .Expect, and with LastCall - it actually works. Any thoughts? I have changed the code above, to reflect the problem.

Comment: What version of Rhino Mocks are you using? I'm trying to recall the history, but I *think* this is/was a known bug with rhino mocks. Can you put together a stand-alone, code-complete example of this issue so we can reproduce it ourselves?

Comment: 3.6.0 I can try, but probably it won't work - I have a lot of unit tests, and there are a lot of generic methods there. For some reason only this throws an exception. I yet didn't find any differences

Comment: @vcsjones I made an update to the post, could you take a look?

Comment: This one also interesting: when I setup an expectation via extension methods like .Expect() or .Stub() - fails NEXT method, not the one I set up

Answer (score 0):

This issue was corrected with version 3.6.1

I do not believe that it should be an issue to update from version 3.6.0 as all of the constructs remain